# Can not return "result" in xhr.then ('dojo/request/xhr')

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo

I have some problems when I return "result" in xhr.then() and I use dojo 1.10.4 Pls help me!

**The below code which connects to API with xhr ('dojo/request/xhr') in dojo:**

```
remandFlow: function(postData, flowId) {
        return xhr(this.REMAND_URL + flowId, {
            method: 'POST',
            data: postData,
            handleAs: 'json',
            headers: {'X-CSRFToken': cookie("csrftoken")}
        }).then(
            lang.hitch(this, function(result){
                return result;
            }),
            lang.hitch(this, function(error){
                return error;
            })
        );
    },
```

**The below code which gets result of above code:**

```
editStepUser: function(stepComponent, routeComponent) {

        this.model.remandFlow(postData).then(
            function(result){
                console.log(result) //I can not get it, It's undefined
                result.targeted_step_id = postData.route_step_id;
            },
            function(result){
                result.targeted_step_id = postData.route_step_id;
            }
        );
    },
```

**So, in the second code, I can't get result, result is "undefined". Please help me, I'm a newbie dojo.**

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

What happen if you test like that ??

```js
remandFlow: function(postData, flowId) {
        // edit : added console.log
        console.log('remandFlow : ' , postData , '|' , flowId);
        console.log('remandFlow => this.REMAND_URL : ' , this.REMAND_URL);


        return xhr(this.REMAND_URL + flowId, {
            method: 'POST',
            data: postData,
            handleAs: 'json',
            headers: {'X-CSRFToken': cookie("csrftoken")}
        }).then(
                function( result ){ return result; } ,
                function( error  ){ return error;  }
            /*
            lang.hitch(this, function(result){
                return result;
            }),
            lang.hitch(this, function(error){
                return error;
            })
            */
        );
    },
```

Comment: Anonymous0day, thanks for your answer, but the result is undefined as well

Comment: if this part is correct `return xhr(this.REMAND_URL + flowId)` check from your debugger tool that you receive data from server !

Comment: I checked it. I can see data which is returned when I use debug tool

Comment: replace `function( result ){ return result; } ,` by : `function( result ){ console.log(arguments); return result; } ,` and tell me if you see something in your debugger ?

Comment: I just see "undefined" in console. There are no any errors in debug tool

Comment: no it is not possible at least it log `[]`, try with : `console.log('len : ' + arguments.length)`

Comment: Anonymous0day Are there any other way to get "result" parameter in the second code.

Comment: Your problem don't come from second code but first, you will never have a result in second if first don't have it ! see my edit on my answer code , try it and tell me what happen

Comment: I replaced your code to the first. I saw "len : 1". So, what's happened,  Anonymous0day

Comment: ok good point for that, so we receive something, replace it by  `console.log('firstArgument : ' + arguments[0])` and tell me what you see

Comment: the next good point =]], I saw "firstArgument : [object Object]"

Comment: replace `return result;` by `return arguments[0]` and tell me if the second function catch it or no

Comment: Hey bro. I resolved my problem, so I will post my answer to you can learn. You are very kind and thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

**In the first code, I will use deferred to return a deferred.promise. This's my way:**

```
declare(['dojo/Deferred',.....], function(Deferred,....){ 

remandFlow: function(postData, flowId) {
        var deferred = new Deferred();

        xhr(this.REMAND_URL + flowId, {
            method: 'POST',
            data: postData,
            handleAs: 'json',
            headers: {'X-CSRFToken': cookie("csrftoken")}
        }).then(
            lang.hitch(this, function(result){
                deferred.resolve(result);
            }),
            lang.hitch(this, function(error){
                deferred.reject(error);
            })
        );

        return deferred.promise;
    },
```

Comment: You have two return in the same function the second return is ignored ! `return deferred.promise;`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: you wrote : `function(){ return a ; return b;};` your return b is never reached

Comment: Oh, I'm sory. I fixed. Thanks bro :D